# Generating multiple versions of a document from a single MS Word doc

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

How I do conditionally remove content from an MS word document in order to produce different versions of it? Ideally, I would like to set a flag somewhere to do this and then "mark" the content.

EDIT: Upon KnotWright's helpful suggestion, I am adding more info.

I have a software that is sold under 3 different licenses (basic, intermediate and advanced). The "advanced" license is the full version of the software and the other versions include only a subset of the software's functionality. The software manual for the basic/intermediate versions shouldn't contain material related to the "advanced" version.

The main idea is that we have a single manual and when the time comes to produce a manual for each license, we "flip" a switch to include/exclude some content and generate 3 manuals, slightly different to one another, from a single source file.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve and clarify how you'd like to get there?

Comment: I have a software that is sold under 3 different licenses ( basic, intermediate and advanced). The "advanced" license is the full version of the software and the other versions include only a subset of the software's functionality.

The software manual for the basic/intermediate versions shouldn't contain material related to the "advanced" version.

The main idea is that we have a single manual and when the time comes to produce a manual for each license, we "flip" a switch to include/exclude some content and generate 3 manuals, slightly different to one another, from a single source file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @melanie93.  Please consider editing your question to include the clarification and what if anything you've tried, considered or achieved.  I think there are a number of routes to your destination and a clearer question should pull in some useful responses.

Comment: @KnotWright Thank you

Comment: I can't help you with this in MS Word, but are you willing to consider other software for generating documents? Such as LaTeX? Or something that compiles HTML or Markdown into a PDF using a script?

Comment: I would consider other solutions but the main problem is that whoever edits the content of the manual needs to be familiar with LaTex/HTML/etc and not get confused by the tags that are mixed in.